# heroku upgrade rubygems

Tags: rubygems, heroku

The rubygems version on my local is `1.8.10` but on heroku is `1.3.7`. I see the following errors in heroku logs.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails31/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000103d160b0> 3.2.0"]
```

On googling i found that i will need to upgrade rubygems. But could not find out how to upgrade rubygems on a heroku cedar stack. Does anyone know if its possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't upgrade Rubygems as such as it's part of the curated platform.  You might be able to do something whizzy with the [Heroku buildpacks](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

To be honest though, I'm not sure that's the actual problem you're suffering from.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1392